# Capistrano 3.0 file transfers?

Tags: ruby, upload, capistrano, transfer

Seems like Capistrano used to have [an extensive file transfer package](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/09/capistrano-file-transfer-actions/).

However, it seems to be gone in version 3.0 after the rewrite. Any idea if there is some alternative way to still transfer files to/from servers?

Comment: There is a `download!` function now https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/blob/v0.0.34/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb#L82

Answer (score 10):

To download:

```
desc "download foobar.txt into local_dir/"
task :foobar do
  download! "some_remote_path/foobar.txt", "local_dir/"
end
```

I know this works as of Cap 3.2.1, as I'm using it right now.

Comment: Note that the remote path must be ABSOLUTE, not relative. (I.e. the same as what you'd type when doing an `scp` command directly.) For example, you can do `download! "#{release_path}/path/within/project", "local_dir/"`

Answer (score 6):

I asked about this on IRC and found that there is still an upload function:

```
on hosts do |host|
  upload! '/config/database.yml', '/opt/my_project/shared/database.yml'
end
```

https://github.com/leehambley/sshkit/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md
However I have yet to find a way to download files from the server without using rsync or scp

Comment: I use rsync and scp for filetransfers

Answer (score 3):

You could use rsync

```
run_locally do
execute"rsync -ah --progress source destination"
end
```